# Comparar datos de un archivo txt y abrir Activity

Tags: android

Estoy realizando una aplicación android, esta aplicación lee un archivo txt con datos, el archivo `txt` es enviado via `bluetooth` mediante una RaspBerry con algunos datos, nombre, status, edad, direccion, y otros datos personales, la aplicacion me recibe el archivo txt y en una caja de texto, me imprime los datos que hay en el archivo txt.

Ahora quiero que después de que los lea, haga una comparación de acuerdo al dato status, este status puede ser activo o inactivo y dependiendo de el tipo de status sea, mande llamar otra `activity`.

----EJEMPLO DE LOS DATOS DEL TXT------------------------------------------------

```
status: Activo,
nombre: prueba,
edad: prueba
```

---------------METODO QUE ABRE EL TXT EN LA APLICACION---------------

```
 private void Abrir() {
    //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Modified Date :- " + sdf.format(f.lastModified()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Instanciamos un ArrayList

    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Obtenemos la ruta interna del dispositivo móvil
    File ruta_in = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // Introducimos la ruta de la carpeta Download en un File
    File f = new File(ruta_in.getAbsolutePath() + "/bluetooth/");
    // Metemos en un arreglo lo que devuelve el array de File con los directorios hijos
    File[] files = f.listFiles();


    // Agregamos uno por uno los nombres de los archivos en el ArrayList
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)

    {
        File file = files[i];

        if (file.isDirectory()){

        }
        else{
            item.add(file.getName());
        }
    }


    // Recuperamos una vez mas la ruta pero en este caso la ruta del ultimo archivo que se recibio via bluetooth
    File ff = new File(ruta_in.getAbsolutePath() + "/bluetooth/" + item.get(item.size()-1));

    // Adicionamos en un buffer el archivo para poder leerlo linea por linea y concatenarlas en el EditText
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ff));
        String linea = br.readLine();
        String todo = "";
        while (linea != null){
            todo += linea + "\n";
            linea = br.readLine();
        }
        text.setText(todo);

    }catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pudes obtener el valor del "estatus" de esta forma, al leer la linea que contenga "status:" y obtener su valor, lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
   if(linea.toLowerCase().contains("status:")){
        //Obtiene valor de status, creando un array.
        String arrayStatus[] = linea.toLowerCase().split(":");
        if(arrayStatus[1] != null){
            //Elimina coma y espacios para obtener valor
            valorStatus = arrayStatus[1].replace(",","").trim();
        }
    }
```

este sería el código completo:

```
    ...
    ...
    while (linea != null){
        todo += linea + "\n";
        linea = br.readLine();

    /*----------------------------------*/
    String valorStatus = "";
    if(linea.toLowerCase().contains("status:")){
        //Obtiene valor de status
        String arrayStatus[] = linea.toLowerCase().split(":");
        if(arrayStatus[1] != null){
            //Elimina coma y espacios para obtener valor
            valorStatus = arrayStatus[1].replace(",","").trim();
        }
    }

    //compara con valor "activo" o "inactivo" para determinar que activity abrir.
    if(valorStatus.equals("activo")){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityActivo.class));
    }else if(valorStatus.equals("inactivo")){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityInactivo.class));
    }

   /*----------------------------------*/
   }
   text.setText(todo);
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, solo que tengo un pequeño inconveniente, en la linea de:  text.setText(todo) 
Concatenaba todo lo que venia dentro del archivo y lo mandaba a una caja de texto dentro de la aplicacion, despues de implementarlo, ya no me lo añade, se podra solucionar?

Comment: Hola  @Joss, que sucede con  text.setText(todo)  , aquí muestras en el textView el contenido del archivo.

Comment: Hola Elenasys, perdón por la tardanza, en efecto, en la ventana principal tengo un textview donde se muestra todo el contenido del archivo, estoy usando un alertdialog para mandar el mensaje de si es activo o no y si es activo mandarlo a otra activity, esto ultimo me funciona con la forma en que me proporcionaste, pero ya no me lleno el textview con la informacion del archivo.

Comment: text.setText(todo); debe estar después del while, se supone que el while almacena el texto en la variable "todo" , asegura que se encuentre después del while-

Comment: Quite el while, ya que el dato se me perdia con el while. ahora no lo tengo

Comment: Ya lo solucione, el while lo puse debajo de los if, ya que si lo dejaba se perdia el dato, puesto que me imagino que tomaba el ultimo dato del archivo. muchisimas gracias ya quedo solucionado esto